# Reference for a theorem of Tate on the endomorphism rings of AVs over finite fields

Tags: reference-request, abelian-varieties, nt.number-theory

Let $k$ be a finite field, and $A$, $B$ abelian varieties over $k$. Let $T_p(A)$, $T_p(B)$ be
the (contravariant) Dieudonn\'e modules associated to the p-divisible groups attached to $A$ and $B$, respectively. The theorem of Tate in the question is that the natural map

${\rm Hom}_k(A,B)\otimes\mathbf{Z}_p\longrightarrow{\rm Hom}(T_p(B),T_p(A))$

is an isomorphism.

It seems to me that the standard reference for the proof of this theorem is a paper of Tate titled *Endomorphisms of abelian varieties over finite fields. II* that should have appeared 50 years ago in Inventiones but, I am right, never did.

Is there another reference in the literature for the proof of this theorem?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, may be I should have said 40 years go

Comment: Minor point: when $A$ and $B$ are not the same variety, one usually uses $\operatorname{Hom}$ instead of $\operatorname{End}$

Comment: Thanks. You are perfectly right. I guess I was thinking to the case A=B... I'll fix it.


Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the result appears in:

Waterhouse, W. C.; Milne, J. S.: Abelian varieties over finite fields. 1969 Number Theory Institute (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XX, State Univ. New York, Stony Brook, N.Y., 1969), pp. 53–64. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1971

Comment: and this is available online at Professor Milne's website
http://jmilne.org/math/articles/1971a.pdf

Answer (score 8):

I guess $p=\operatorname{char}(k)$. For another (unified) proof of Tate's theorem (that works for primes $\ell\ne p$ and $\ell=p$) see [arXiv:0711.1615](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1615) [math.AG]; MR2484084 (2010a:11117).

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow, Professor Zarhin. I've taken the liberty of adding an explicit link to your Arxiv preprint.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the characteristic of $k$ being $p$. And thanks as well for the interesting reference!

Comment: As I was browsing through the preprint, it took me a few moments to realize why the author wasn't calling it 'Zarhin's trick'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not treated by CP Ramanujan in an appendix to Mumford's book on abelian varieties ?

Comment: I don't know. I will take a look though, thanks.

Comment: @Dalawat: The appendix in Mumford's book treats the $\ell \neq p$ case (Galois modules), but the OP's question seems to be about the $p$-divisible group case.